# C++ char-by-char comparison of a string

Tags: c++, string, comparison

I'm trying to work on a string comparison check for an introductory C++ course; it's an online course and unfortunately the instructor is not very responsive.  For a current lab, I need to perform a number of manipulations on string data.

Currently, I'm working on a step to check if a string has any repeated characters, and if a repetition is found, to delete the repeated characters at their present spot and move one copy of the letter to the beginning of the string. This is only to be done for the first double to be found.

I've set up a basic counter to move through the string looking for matches, checking a stored character (updated on each iteration) to the current position in the string.

I tried multiple string functions (comparing the current `inputString[i]` to the previous such, stored as a second string tempStore), but those always gave char conversion errors. I've tried the below instead, but this is now giving an error: "invalid conversion from 'char' to '`const char*`'.

`inputString` is given by the user, `testA` and `testB` are defined as type char

Any ideas?

```
while (opComplete == false) {

    if (i == 0) {
        i++;
    }

    else if (i == inputString.size()) {
        //Not Found
        opComplete = true;
    }

    else if (i > 0) {

        testA = inputString[i-1];
        testB = inputString[i];

        if (strcmp(testA,testB) != 0) {
            i++;
        }

        else {
            inputString.insert(0,inputString[i]);
            inputString.erase(i,1);
            inputString.erase(i-1,1);
            opComplete = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How did you declare `testA` and `testB`?

Comment: Hi -- basic char declare:    char testA, testB;

Comment: When `testA` and `testB` are of type `char` you cannot pass them into `strcmp`, as this function expects strings. Just compare them with the the equality operator (`==`) instead!

Comment: Thank you, Markus!  That fixed the first issue.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
inputString.insert(0,inputString[i]);
```

The `std::string.insert()` function the way you call it here has the following signature:

```
string& insert ( size_t pos1, const char* s );
```

so it expects a `const char` pointer. You, however, are giving it the `inputString[i]`. The return value of `std::string.operator[]` is a reference (as [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)), hence the error. However, by the time you reach your `else`, you already have the desired character in your `testB` variable, so you can just change the line to

```
 inputString.insert(0, &testB);
```

You also can't pass normal `char`s into `strcmp`. You can use `operator==`, or, in your case, `operator!=` though.

Comment: Singer, thank you very much.  I've got it working now, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `insert` method incorrectly, check its reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) for possible arguments.

```
while (opComplete == false)
{
    if (i == 0)
    i++;

    else if (i == inputString.size())
    opComplete = true;

    else if (i > 0) {
    char testA = inputString[i-1];
    char testB = inputString[i];

    if(testA!=testB)
    i++;

    else {
        inputString.insert(0,&testB); //Problem Corrected here.
        inputString.erase(i,1);
        inputString.erase(i-1,1);
        opComplete = true;
    }
    }
}
```